# How do I give a user access to show their own content OR public content in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Here is my current controller:

```
def show

    @lesson = @current_user.lessons.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html # show.html.erb
        format.json { render json: @lesson }
    end
end
```

Currently users can only access their own lessons. If they go to example.com/lessons/[other person's public lesson id] then it doesn't show.

I would like to give users access to show their own lessons or other people's lessons if the `lesson` table's column `public` is true in the other person's lesson. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working:

```
def show

    begin
        @lesson = @current_user.lessons.find(params[:id])
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
        @lesson = Lesson.where("public = ? AND id = ?", true, (params[:id]))[0]
    end


    respond_to do |format|
        format.html # show.html.erb
        format.json { render json: @lesson }
    end
end
```

Is there anything unsafe or unsustainable about this?